# how to change html content in angular

Tags: jquery, angular

JavaScript can change HTML content like this:

```html
<p id="demo">JavaScript can change HTML content.</p>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Hello JavaScript!'">Click Me!</button>
```

jQuery can change HTML content like this:

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    $("#demo").html("Hello JQuery!");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo">JQuery can change HTML content.</p>
<button type="button" >Click Me!</button>
```

AngularJS can change HTML content like this:

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p id="demo">{{content}}</p>
  <button type="button" ng-click=changeHtmlContent()>Click Me!</button>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.content="AngularJs can change HTML content." 
    $scope.changeHtmlContent = function() {
    $scope.content = "Hello Angular Js!";
  };
});
</script>
```

I want to do the same thing using the Angular component. But it is not working.

```javascript
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <p id="demo">{{content}}</p>
  <button type="button" ng-click=changeHtmlContent()>Click Me!</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  content:string="Angular2 can change HTML content";
  constructor() {}
  //this data may come from api
  changeHtmlContent(){
  this.content ="Hello Angular2 !"
  }
}
```

Comment: Which backend are you using? Is your function is calling?

Comment: @Mayur Patel I have edited the question and given my code...

Comment: @Darshak Gajjar it is not working in angular 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `(click)`:

```
<button type="button" (click)="changeHtmlContent()">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: @Md.SaifulIslam Check it as answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

I think [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-2-html-binding) is solution for you.

```
<p id="demo" [innerHTML]="content"></p>
```